Polarization, quantum number associated with
Why does a photon with left circular polarization has a +1 angular momentum $lz$, while a photon with right circular polarization has a -1 angular momentum, instead of left circular polarization having -1 and right, +1?
Also, in solid state systems, there are transitions that are photon polarization selective. I believe any sort of photon absorption based transitions comes down to the dipole term driven by the electric field component of the said photon. Does this mean if I want to activate certain transitions with the selection rule in mind, I have to pay close attention to the angle between the incident photon with a specific polarization and the dipole vector of the system you are trying to drive?
Additionally, the surface of the sample the circularly polarized photons are hitting will see the E field that is rotating. When you take a cross section of a propagating E&M field and look at it in time, E and B field are going to be going around in a circle. Then, I feel like whether it's left or right circular polarization, the electric field component of the light should be able to drive whatever dipole you have in your solid state system.
Could someone provide an intuitive explanation of why $lz$ is associated with polarization of photons, and how polarization selective transitions come about? and also, do we need to think about the angle of attack to accurately predict the transition probability?

Please restructure post to have only 1 important question and for the others - register new Physics SE posts.

It comes from the definition of the polarization vectors in Cartesian coordinates. Essentially $\vec{e}_{\pm}=\frac 1 {\sqrt{2}} \left(\vec{e}_x\pm i\vec{e}_y\right)$ where the helicity bases are labeled appropriately.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.


Why does a photon with left circular polarization has a +1 angular momentum lz
, while a photon with right circular polarization has a -1 angular momentum, instead of left circular polarization having -1 and right, +1?

This picture taken from spin angular momentum wiki explains it nicely :

Left circular EM field polarization has angular momentum vector component $J_z = +\hbar$, because it's direction is towards receiver, i.e. collinear to EM wave propagation direction. And right circular EM field polarization has angular momentum vector component $J_z = -\hbar$, because it's direction is outwards from receiver, i.e. anti-collinear to EM wave propagation direction. This convention is standard in optics.
